# Why ggscatter does not work with NA in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter

I am trying to plot a direct correlation between A and B with `ggscatter`, however, I have many `NAs`, since the variables were not measured the same day.
Therefore, no correlation coefficient appears. Is there any way of "omitting" or ignoring these NAs?

```
library("ggpubr")

data<- data.frame(
      Days=c(0,2,4,6,7,9,10,13,14,18,22,25,30),
      A=c(NA,678,1698,NA,3484,NA,3322,NA,3776,3279,3182,3438,2689),
      B= c(300,1000,NA,3000,NA,3500,NA,4000,NA,NA,5000,NA,NA))

ggscatter(data, x = "A", y = "B", 
          add = "reg.line", 
          conf.int = TRUE, 
          cor.coef = TRUE, 
          cor.method = "pearson",
          xlab = "A", ylab = "B")
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I get it from the docs the NAs (see ?stat_cor) are already removed by default. In the case of your example data the issue is that there are only 2 obs, e.g. if you replace one NA with a finite value both the R2 as well as the cor coeff show up.

Comment: Try using `na.omit(data)`. You will find only 2 complete rows in your dataset. With only 2 points the correlation is always 1 or -1 (see the output of `with(na.omit(data), cor(A, B)))` and no confidence intervals can be estimated.